# Change Drupal's default styling

Tags: theming

I'm starting to build a new Drupal site with the core theme "Stark" (Almost no styling) but I can't seem to find where the default body background(grey) is coming from so I can change it. (I'm good with CSS).

Answer (score 1):

stark.css doesn't contain any background colour,  so you can set one yourself.  you don't need to remove anything first.

Comment: Drupal core has styling by itself which affects any theme. If you inspect element of the body in Stark, you will see #ccc.

Comment: are you sure you're not seeing a style applied by your web browser?

I have never seen inline css from a drupal core function.  you're supposed to put all your CSS in your theme's css file.

Comment: It's not inline. This is how it looks. body {background: #ccc;}     (index):204

Comment: drupal 7?  and what browser are you using?

Comment: @jdu Yes, I'm using Drupal 7 and Google Chrome.

Comment: @Esser Doesn't look like that's coming from core. The explicit bg colours for all core themes are #fff (seven) and #edf5fa (garland). The body background colour isn't set by any core module, so it must be a contrib module, theme, or browser stylesheet. If you inspect the body element in chrome it'll tell you what file the style is coming from (or whether it's the browser default)

Comment: I inspected it and it doesn't tell me a file name, just `(index):204` but I don't know what the index is.

Comment: Yeah that's probably the UA stylesheet then. Look for "user agent stylesheet" somewhere around that to confirm